# Is it correct to say "I was born on the 2nd of August of 1996"?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if it is correct to say "I was born on the 2nd of August of 1996" and if there are other ways to say when a person was born.

Comment: Some more details please.  Why do you have a doubt about this phrase? Why this phrase and not some other? In what context would you need to use this?  What is the situation in which you need to tell some the date on which you were born.  What research have you done already?  Just comment below and somebody can [edit] it into your question for you.

Comment: I'm not certain of the grammatical reasons for it, but generally the second "of" is omitted so that it's "2nd of August, 1996". Of course, in America, the day/month order is usually reversed, so it'd instead be "August 2, 1996".

Comment: In British English it can be said or written either way round; it's only when writing a date in all figures that we always put them in order of magnitude (D/M/Y).